# How to write multiple data via looping to excel (Jxl)

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, jxl

In my below code, I want to write multiple data to excel but it's writing only the first value and not the remaining.

I am trying to read from webpage and write it to a excel sheet. Below is set of code works fine, but i am not able to figure out how to run this in a loop. As i have to write many value which i am reading from the table

Could anybody sort this out.

```
String m1 = (driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dhfdshjfdsfdsf']")).getText());
   System.out.println(m1);
    WritableWorkbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\\output_2.xls"));
    writableSheet ws = wb.createSheet("customsheet",1);
    {
    Label label = new Label(0,0,m1);
    ws.addCell(label);
    }
    wb.write();
    wb.close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve the Exception in thread main](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184211/how-to-resolve-the-exception-in-thread-main)

Comment: you need to put  wb.write(); and   wb.close(); outside the loop, then it will write all the values

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code to write for multiple values. Check once with below code.

```
WritableWorkbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\\output_2.xls"));
    writableSheet ws = wb.createSheet("customsheet",1);
    int rowsize = ws.getRows();
    int c=0;

    //if m1 contains 20 values then it upadtes till 20 rows
    for(int i=rowsize; i<rowsize+20; i++) {
        String m1 = (driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dhfdshjfdsfdsf']")).getText());
        System.out.println(m1);
        Label label = new Label(c,i,m1);
        ws.addCell(label);
    }
    wb.write();
    wb.close();
```